# Show that $I \otimes_R J \to I \cdot J, i \otimes j \mapsto i \cdot j$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

i have the following problem:
Let $R$ be a commutative Ring and $f \in R$ not a zero divisor. $ I = (f), J \subseteq R$ ideals. Show that $I \otimes_R J \to I \cdot J, i \otimes j \mapsto i \cdot j$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

Im relatively new to tensor products and have a hard time proving statements about them. I hope this problem gives me a good intuition on how to tackle these kinds of problems.

Comment: An isomorphism of $R$-modules? Did you first check it is well-defined? linear? onto?

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion. I have tried to do this but as i said i basically havent shown anything about tensorproducts so i dont really know how to check for such things in this setting.

Comment: Hint: $I\cong R$ and $R\otimes_RJ\cong J$ as $R$-modules.

Comment: But can we really show that $I \cong R$? I mean for example let $2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $(2) \ncong \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $(2)$ _is_ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Comment: ah i see. But how can we generaly obtain a map from $I$ to $R$ s.th. it is an R-module-isomorphism. Sorry if it is trivial, but i am little bit confused

Comment: $I=(f)=fR$ is isomorphic to $R$ via $fx \mapsto x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct and conceptually clean. However, I think the OP would also benefit from a prove a beginner would've been able to come up with.

I will not prove in detail that the map is well-defined.  (E.g., if $i$ and $j$ are the inclusion maps $I\subset R$ and $J\subset R$ and if $m\colon R\otimes_R R\to R$ is the multiplication map, observe that the map in question is obtained from $m\circ (i\otimes j)$.)

To see that the map $\varphi\colon I\otimes_R J\to IJ\subset R$ is surjective, note that $IJ$ is generated by the elements of the form $gh=\varphi(g\otimes h)$ for $g\in I,h\in J$.

The injectivity is the interesting bit since it's the only place where we have to use that $I=(f)$ for a non-zero divisor $f\in R$. A general element of $I\otimes_R J$ is a finite sum $x=\sum_i g_i\otimes h_i$ for certain elements $g_i\in I$, $h_i\in J$. Assume that $\varphi(x)=0$; I claim that $x=0$ then.

Since $I=(f)$, there exist elements $a_i\in R$ such that $g_i=fa_i$. Hence,
$$x=\sum\nolimits_i fa_i\otimes h_i=\sum\nolimits_i f\otimes a_ih_i=f\otimes\left(\sum\nolimits_i a_i h_i\right).$$
Therefore, to show that $x=0$, it suffices to show that $\sum\nolimits_i a_i h_i=0$.

To this end, note that by assumption
$$0=\varphi(x)=\sum\nolimits_i f a_i h_i= f\sum\nolimits_i a_i h_i$$ and since $f$ is a non-zero divisor, this implies that, indeed, $\sum\nolimits_i a_i h_i=0$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is injective, as claimed.

Note carefully that whenever I've moved factors around beyond $\otimes$, at every stage the left-hand side is an element of $I$ and the right-hand side is an element of $J$. (E.g., something seemingly easier like $x=\sum_i fa_i\otimes h_i=\sum_i1\otimes fa_ih_i=1\otimes \varphi(x)=0$ would be fallacious. We can't move over $fa_i\otimes h_i\neq 1\otimes fa_ih_i$ because $1\not\in I$ (in general), but we can move over just $a_i$ to obtain $fa_i\otimes h_i= f\otimes a_ih_i$. This is why we have to take the detour of making sure that not just $\sum_i fa_ih_i=0$ but actually $\sum_i a_ih_i=0$.)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just me going through the details of Fabio's hint.

---

**Fact 1: We first want to show that, as $R$-modules, $R$ and $I$ are isomorphic.**

Let's define a map $\phi: R\to I$ by $r\mapsto rf$. We need to check that this is really a homomorphism of $R$-modules. To this end, we first need to check that $\phi(r + s) = \phi(r) + \phi(s)$. Doing the computations, we get
$$\phi(r + s) = (r+s)f = rf + sf = \phi(r) + \phi(s).$$
We now need to check that $\phi(rs) = r\phi(s)$ for all $r\in R$. Again, a quick computation shows us that
$$\phi(rs) = rsf = r(sf) = r\phi(s).$$
Therefore, our map $\phi$ really is well-defined.

We now need to check that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, i.e., bijective. Let's first show injectivity.
$$\phi(r) = \phi(s) \implies rf = sf \implies rf - sf = 0 \implies (r-s)f = 0.$$
Since $f$ isn't a zero divisor, then $(r-s)f = 0$ means that $r - s = 0$, i.e., that $r = s$. This shows that our map is injective. Now let's see why it's surjective. Suppose that $x\in I$. By definition of $I$, there exists some $r\in R$ satisfying $x = rf$. Therefore $\phi(r) = rf = x$, and so $\phi$ is surjective. This shows that $\phi$ is a bijective $R$-module homomorphism!! An isomorphism it is, and so $R\cong I$. This can be slightly hard to grasp, as they seem different -- $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a proper ideal! But remember, we're only showing that they're isomorphic as *R-Modules*, not as rings or as ideals. Similar to how $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ aren't isomorphic as fields or as $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, but they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces. It just depends on what structure we're focusing on.

---

**Fact 2: We now want to show that $J$ and $R\otimes_R J$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules.**

We now wish to define a map $\psi: R\otimes_R J \to J$. To do this, we start by defining an $R$-bilinear map $\Psi: R\times J\to J$ and then invoking the [universal property of tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) to get an $R$-module homomorphism $\psi$. We define $\Psi$ by $(r, j)\mapsto rj$. Checking that this is $R$-bilinear amounts to showing the following:

1. For a fixed $r\in R$ the map $\Psi_r: J\to J$, defined by $j\mapsto \Psi(r, j)$, is $R$-linear.
2. For a fixed $j\in J$ the map $\Psi_j: R\to J$, defined by $r\mapsto \Psi(r, j)$, is $R$-linear.

Showing that these conditions hold is analogous to how we showed that $\phi$ was $R$-linear earlier, so I won't go through that. By the universal property, this now induces a map $\psi: R\otimes_R J \to J$ that satisfies $\psi(x\otimes_R y) = \Psi(x, y)$ for all $(x,y)\in R\times J$.

To show that $\psi$ is bijective (i.e., an isomorphism), it suffices to show that it has an inverse, say $\Phi: J\to R\otimes_R J$. This follows from the general fact that if $g: X\to Y$ and $h: Y\to Z$ are composable set functions, then if $h\circ g$ is surjective (resp. injective) then $h$ is surjective (resp. $g$ is injective). Therefore, if we can show that $\psi\circ\Phi$ is surjective and $\Phi\circ\psi$ is injective, then $\psi$ is both injective and surjective.

Let's now define $\Phi$ by $j\mapsto 1\otimes_R j$. Let's first show that $\psi\circ\Phi: J\to J$ is surjective. Let $j\in J$ be any element. Then,
$$\psi\circ\Phi(j) = \psi(1\otimes_R J) = j.$$
This shows that $\psi\circ\Phi$ is the identity map on $J$, thus both injective and surjective.

Now we want to show that $\Phi\circ\psi: R\otimes_R J\to R\otimes_R J$ is injective. Let $x$ be any element of $R\otimes_R J$. By construction of the tensor product, there exist $r_1, \ldots, r_n\in R$ and $j_1, \ldots, j_n\in J$ such that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\otimes_R j_i$ ([see the proposition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Definition)). Recall that the universal property of the tensor product tells us that $\psi(r_i\otimes_R j_i) = \Psi(r_i, j_i)$ for each $i$. Applying this along with linearity of $\psi$ and $\Phi$, we get
$$\Phi\circ\psi(x) = \Phi\circ\psi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\otimes_R j_i\right) = \Phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \psi(r_i\otimes_R j_i)\right) =\\= \Phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n r_ij_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Phi(r_ij_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n 1\otimes_R r_ij_i.$$
However, recall the following fact about the tensor product: if $M, N$ are $R$-module with $M\otimes_R N$ their product, $m\in M$, $n\in N$, and $r\in R$, then $m\otimes_R an = am\otimes_R n$. Applying that to each $1\otimes_R r_ij_i$ gives us the following
$$\Phi\circ\psi(x) =  \sum_{i=1}^n 1\otimes_R r_ij_i = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\otimes_R j_i.$$ But, $x = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\otimes_R j_i$, and so $\Phi\circ\psi$ is the identity map, and therefore necessarily injective.

Since both $\Phi\circ\psi$ and $\psi\circ\Phi$ are the identity map, then $\psi$ is an isomorphism!! This shows that $R\otimes_R J\cong J$ as desired.

---

**Fact 3: Now we wish to show that $J\cong I\cdot J$ as $R$-modules.**

For this one, we define a map $\phi': J\to I\cdot J$. Since $I = (f)$ is a principal ideal, we have that $I\cdot J = \{fj: j\in J\}$. Therefore, we may just define our map by $j\mapsto fj$. Notice that $\phi'$ here is precisely the restriction of our map $\phi$ (in the first fact) to the submodule (or to be even simpler, subset) $J$.  Therefore, it's still a well-defined $R$-module homomorphism and injective. Since $I\cdot J = \{fj: j\in J\}$, then $\phi'$ is immediately surjective by definition, as if $fj\in I\cdot J$ then $\phi'(j) = fg$. Therefore $\phi'$ is an isomorphism, and $J\cong I\cdot J$.

---

**Putting it all together**

1. By Fact 1, $I\otimes_R J\cong R\otimes_R J$.
2. By Fact 2, $R\otimes_R J\cong J$.
3. By Fact 3, $J\otimes I\cdot J$.
4. Hence, $I\otimes_R J\cong I\cdot J$.

By the way we constructed all the isomorphisms, your desired map $i\otimes_R j\mapsto ij$ should pop out after combining them all together. Just be careful with the map for $I\otimes_R J\cong R\otimes_R J$. Here you cannot *just* use $\phi^{-1}$, the inverse of $\phi$, because $\phi^{-1}$ is from $I$ to $R$ and not $I\otimes_R J\to R \otimes_R J$.